# I am struggling with resolving this resource error in xml

Tags: android-layout

I have been struggling with this error for 2 days now and i am at wits end.
building this project in eclipse.according to the sdk this png does not need to be imported. i imported into my drawables anyway after this error generated to no avail.
is anybody willing to point me in the right direction here?

Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@android.drawable/ic_menu_add').
W/ResourceType( 1020): Bad XML block: header size 62 or total size 9767704 is larger than data size 0

```
 //*list_menu.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_insert"
        android:icon="@android.drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="@string/menu_insert"
 />

</menu>

//*strings.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, ReminderListActivity!</string>
<string name="app_name">Task Reminder</string>
<string name="no_reminders">No Reminders Yet</string>
<string name="title">Title</string>
<string name="body">Body</string>
<string name="date">Date</string>
<string name="time">Time</string>
<string name="confirm">Confirm</string>
<string name="menu_insert">Add Reminder</string>


</resources>

//*AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.dummies.android.taskreminder"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".ReminderListActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ReminderEditActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"/>

 </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
android:icon="@android.drawable/ic_menu_add"
```

to

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
```

I believe you need a : not a .

Comment: wow that is embarassing. Thank you for picking up on that. I am curious as to why eclipse did not flag that